# Using the CSS "filter" property with jQueries css method

Tags: jquery, css

It seems I cannot apply the css "filter" property with the .css method in jQuery. Other properties seem to work okay when they are written this way, but not the filter property... jsFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/md2100/fwcdzhu2/

Here's what my current code looks like.

HTML:

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#00ff00">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#0000ff">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Set background-color of p</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").css("filter", "invert(100%)");
});
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the filter property in your code.

Comment: idem, https://jsfiddle.net/fwcdzhu2/3/ but doesnt apply only to bg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `filter` attribute if you are trying to set the filter via .css() - Also, you need to include the browser prefixing to make it work in chrome, opera, and safari.

Keep in mind that `filter` [does not have full cross-browser support!](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter)

`$("p").css({"-webkit-filter": "invert(100%)", "filter": "invert(100%)"});`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fwcdzhu2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Webkit announced they are [dropping prefixing](https://webkit.org/blog/6131/updating-our-prefixing-policy/). Because of this, I would consider cleaning things up a bit. If you need to remove the `-webkit-filter` at some point, removing it from CSS is way less annoying than doing it from JavaScript.

**CSS**

```
.my-filter {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

**JS**

```
$("p").addClass("my-filter");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").css("filter", "invert(100%)");
```